# Use variable into ${ } value expression

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to get data from a method in class call readClientByIdProfessional(), these methods need an 'id' to works, I pass the 'id' from a JSP page to servlets and then when I pass the 'id' doesn´t work and not bring me the data.
Here I declare the variable who get me the 'id':

```
Object idPro = null;
idPro = request.getAttribute("respuesta");
```

And here Im trying to pass the 'id' to ${ } value expression:

```
 <c:forEach var="dato" items="${UserDAO.readClientByIdProfessional(idPro)}">
```

Is the format I am using ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request attributes are directly available as JSP EL variables, so just use `respuesta` directly:

```jsp
<c:forEach var="dato" items="${UserDAO.readClientByIdProfessional(respuesta)}">
```